# Shell command on terminal vs system() call

Tags: linux, system-calls, nmap

I am using NMAP for port scanning on a host. When I run the following command on terminal, it gives the results within a minute most of the times.

```
$ nmap -p 1-65535 10.180.5.237 | awk --posix '{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]/) print $0+0}'
22
80
2404
```

But if I run the same command using ***system()*** call in a C program it takes indefinite time, I am saying it indefinite because I gave more than 7 minutes but no output so stopped the process.

```
if ((system("nmap -p 1-65535 10.180.5.237 | awk --posix '{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]/) print $0+0}' > file_openPorts")) == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR : NMAP port scan error...\n");
      return 1;
 }
```

why is it like that and is there any solution?.

Comment: Do you mean on terminal it *starts* giving the results within a minute most of the times, or it completes the whole execution within a minute? If what happens is that it starts giving the results, you might be seeing the effects of C stdio buffering, where when connected to a terminal it will flush every line, but when redirected to a file it will only flush when it has a lot more data to write...

Comment: Could not reproduce...

Comment: It took 31 sec to completes whole execution without redirecting the output to a file. and I tried redirecting the output to a file, then it took an almost same amount of time(33 sec), and the process completes there.

Comment: Just a note: The `awk` command can be written as `awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]/ { print $0+0 }'`. The `--posix` bit is not needed and it's more common to use "`pattern { action }`" rather than "`{ if (condition) action }`".